# Knockout.js Basic Example - What is causing this databinding to fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Attempting the most basic example of Knockout.js possible on their documentation page:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Looks like I have everything setup like the documentation is asking for, and I'm not getting any errors on the page, but the span should display the binding of "personName" - which is 'Bob'.

However, when I run the page all that appears is "The name is".  Bob is nowhere to be found.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Knockout Practice</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-tmpl.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/knockout-1.2.1.js'></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myViewModel = {
    personName: 'Bob',
    personAge: 123
    };

    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);  
</script>

</head>

<body> 
   The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>


</body> 

</html>
```

Is there something missing in the documentation, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change where the script loads.

> You can either put the script block at the bottom of your HTML document, or you can put it at the top and wrap the contents in a DOM-ready handler such as [jQuery’s $ function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Putting the script block at the end of HTML document does indeed show

> The name is Bob

for `<span data-bind="text: personName">Bob</span>`

Comment: But I currently have it at the top of the document in the <head> tag.  It says you can have the script at the top or bottom - why is it not rendering at the top?

Comment: @Phil You need to wrap it in a handler if you want it at the top. Such that when the DOM is finished loaded (All the HTML is finished) call your code block. By putting it at the end you are letting the whole document load without explicitly having to put it in a handler.

Comment: Ok, looks like the script works only if it's inside the body, or outside of the body - only if it's on the bottom.  I wish there were more complete code examples on the site.  Thanks for your help.